# Using Python - How can I parse CSV list of both integers and strings and add to SQL table through Insert Statement?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, csv

I am automating a task through Python that will run an SQL statement to insert into an existing table in a DB.

My CSV headers look as such:

> ID,ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,REMARK,ISIMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE

My values:

> seq_addnoteid.nextval,123456,TEST,ADMN_TEST,sysdate,ME,This is a test,Y,1,A

NOTE: Currently, seq_addnote works from DB but in my code i added a small snippet to get the max ID and the rows will increase this by one for each iteration.

Sysdate could also be passed as format '19-MAY-22'

If i was to run from DB, this would work:

`insert into notes values(seq_addnoteid.nextval,'123456','TEST','ADMN_TEST',sysdate,'ME','This is a test','Y',1,'A');`

```
    # Snippet to get function
    cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(ID) from NOTES")
    max = cursor.fetchone()
    max = int(max[0])

    
    with open ('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        columns = next(reader)
        query = 'INSERT INTO NOTES({0}) values ({1})'
        query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        for data in reader:
            cursor.execute(query, data)
        conn.commit()
        print("Records inserted successfully")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Currently, i'm getting `Oracle-Error-Message: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` and i think its because of my `query.format` line. However, I'm looking for help to get this code to handle the data types properly.

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Specifically, pandas data frames have a to_sql method with an if_exists=‘append’ keyword argument. So then you just need a package that provides a sql connection object to your database.

Comment: It's much faster to use `executemany()` than `execute()`.  The cx_Oracle documentation has a full example of loading from a CSV file.  See the end of [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try printing your query before you execute it. I think you'll find that it's printing this:

```
INSERT INTO NOTES(ID,ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,REMARK,ISIMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE) 
values(seq_addnoteid.nextval,123456,TEST,ADMN_TEST,sysdate,ME,This is a test,Y,1,A);
```

Which will also give you a ORA-01036 if you try to run it manually.

The problem is that you want some of your column values to be literal values, and some of them to be strings escaped in single-quotes, and your code doesn't do that. I don't think there's an easy to way to do it with `','.join()`, so you'll either need to modify your CSVs to quote the strings, like:

```
seq_addnoteid.nextval,"'123456'","'TEST'","'ADMN_TEST'",sysdate,"'ME'","'This is a test'","'Y'",1,"'A'"
```

Or modify your query.format to add the quotes around the parameters that you want to treat as strings:

```
query.format(','.join(columns), "?,'?','?','?',?,'?','?','?',?,'?'")
```

As the commenters mentioned, pandas does handle this all very nicely.

EDIT: I see what you're saying. I'm not sure pandas will help with the literal functions you want to pass to the insert. But yes, you should be able to change your CSV and then do:

```
query.format(','.join(columns) + ',ID,CREATION_DATE', "'?','?','?','?','?','?',?,'?',seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate")
```

As a side note, a lot of people do this sort of thing on the database side in a BEFORE INSERT trigger, e.g.:

```
create or replace trigger NOTES_INS_TRG
before insert on NOTES
for each row 
begin

:NEW.ID := seq_addnoteid.nextval;
:NEW.CREATION_DATE := sysdate;

end;
/
```

Then you could leave those columns out of your insert entirely.

Edit again:

I'm not sure you can use `?` for bind/substitution variables in cx_oracle ([see documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) ). So where your raw query is currently:

```
INSERT INTO NOTES(ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATED_BY,REMARK,ISIMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE,ID,CREATION_DATE) 
values (seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate,'?','?','?','?','?','?',?,'?')
```

You'd need something like:

```
INSERT INTO NOTES(ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATED_BY,REMARK,ISIMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE,ID,CREATION_DATE) 
values (seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8)
```

We can probably do that by modifying the format string again to generate some bind variables:

```
query.format('ID,CREATION_DATE,' + ','.join(columns), 
             "seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate," + ','.join([':'+c for c in columns])
```

Again, try printing the query before executing it to make sure the column names and values are lining up correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look up and implement Pandas for v2. If i want to hard code in values that wouldn't change on any sql like `seq_addnoteid.nextval` or `sysdate` is it possible in using query.format?

Ideally, i would like to change my csv to 123456,TEST,ADMN_TEST,ME,This is a test,Y,1,A

Comment: Made some changes and used pandas:
`
data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for row in df.intertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
         INSERT INTO notes (ID,ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,REMARK,IS_IMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE) values (seq.addnoteid.nextval,?,?,?,sysdate,?,?,?,1,A)''',
    
    row.ACCOUNTID,
    row.CATEGORY,
    row.SUBCATEGORY,
    row.CREATED_BY,
    row.REMARK,
    row.IS_IMPORTANT)

`

Sorry about formatting. Character limit. 

TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments

Comment: @MarkT - updated answer with more details - see if that helps

Comment: Update: I've removed the columns for ID and CREATED_BY from my csv and hard coded them in using `query.format(','.join(columns) + ',ID,CREATION_DATE', "'?','?','?','?','?','?',?,'?',seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate")` I'm still getting an `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Comment: Hmm could you try adding a `print(query)` after the query.format() line to see what the final query is?

Comment: It returns: `INSERT INTO NOTES(ACCOUNTID,CATEGORY,SUBCATEGORY,CREATED_BY,REMARK,ISIMPORTANT,TYPE,ENTITY_TYPE,ID,CREATION_DATE) values (seq_addnoteid.nextval,sysdate,'?','?','?','?','?','?',?,'?')`

Comment: Interesting that it rearranged the column values. I guess move the + to the front of the columns to match: `'ID,CREATION_DATE,' + ','.join(columns)`

Comment: It looks better now. But, shouldn't it print the values instead of '?' ?
I'm wondering if that's where i've went astray

Comment: The actual data gets substituted in during `cursor.execute()`. Although... aren't you using cx_oracle? Looking at [the bind variables it supports](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html), I don't think you can use `?`. I'll edit my answer again. Sorry!